# Show pictures which represent kmeans cluster center (Scikit learn)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a dataset which was clustered by kmeans. A Friend told me that i can show the pictures which represent each cluster center. He gave's me this short example code:

```
for i in xrange(len(np.unique(labels))):
     this_cluster = np.where(labels == i)[0]
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(this_cluster))
     for im in this_cluster:
        ax.imshow(images[im])
```

I've tried this but it's not working...for e.g I have a small dataset which contains 20 pics. Kmeans returns 50 Centers for this 20 pics. So my np.unique(labels) with (labels = kmeans.labels_?!) is equal to 50...so the "i" runs from 0 to 49...my first "this_cluster" looks like this one:

```
[   4    8   18   19   35   37   50  135  140  146  156  214  371  506  563
  586  594  887  916  989  993 1021 1061 1105 1121 1128 1405 1409 1458 1466
 1481 1484 1505 1572 1573 1620 1784 1817 1835 1854 1945 1955 2004 2006 2054
 2135 2204 2245 2319 2321 2343 2391 2410 2414 2486 2502 2530 2594 2624 2629
 2825 2828 2833 2911 3017 3097 3245 3246 3298 3347 3493 3568 3627 3677 3701
 3789 3866 3941 3944 3969 4022 4115 4214 4215 4432 4527 4559 4594 4645 4668
 4699 4785 4797 4802 4807 4831 4892 4905 4921 4929 4932 5076 5178 5233 5249
 5318 5463 5508 5571 5621 5644 5661 5678 5690 5727 5736 5737 5755 5777 5961
 6088 6089 6107 6197 6353 6487 6500 6515 6565 6575 6601 6706 6749]
```

so if the next for begans it breaks by `i=4` because there are only 20 pictures and `images[im]` with `im>20` will give me a out of bounds...i think "this_clusters" are the Descriptors taken from the dataset which are compute by kmeans and set to cluster 0...so this can't be right?! or am i on the wrong way. Maybe someone could help me.

EDIT*:

```
create sets

X_train_pos, X_test_pos, X_dataset_train_pos, X_dataset_test_pos  = train_test_split(X_desc_pos, dataset_pos, test_size=0.5) 
  X_train_neg, X_test_neg, X_dataset_train_neg, X_dataset_test_neg = train_test_split(X_desc_neg,  dataset_neg, test_size=0.5) 
  # merge list of array descriptor into descriptor list
  x1 = numpy.vstack(X_train_pos)
  x2 = numpy.vstack(X_train_neg)

  # compute cluster centers 
  kmeans, n_clusters = dataset_module.create_center_data(numpy.vstack((x1,x2)),numpy.vstack((X_dataset_train_pos,X_dataset_train_neg)))
```

compute kmeans

```
def create_center_data(data,dataset): 
    n_clusters = len(data)
    n_clusters = math.sqrt(n_clusters/2)
    n_clusters = int(n_clusters)
    kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=1)
    kmeans.fit(data)
    numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
    labels = kmeans.labels_
    for i in xrange(len(numpy.unique(labels))):
        this_cluster = numpy.where(labels == i)[0]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(this_cluster))
        for im in this_cluster:
            pic = open(dataset[im], "rb")
            ax.imshow(pic)
    return kmeans, n_clusters
```

data looks like:

```
[[ 36.   1.   9. ...,   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   1. ...,   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...,   0.   0.   1.]
 ..., 
 [ 49.  26.   0. ...,  12.   4.   5.]
 [  0.   0.   0. ...,   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   3.   8. ...,   0.   0.   3.]]
```

data = all descriptors of the 20 pictures...

dataset is a numpy array with paths to pictures

regards

Linda

Comment: If you only have 20 data points, then you're making two mistakes. One is to try and find 50 clusters in 20 samples, which makes no sense. The other is that you're feeding your data to `KMeans.fit` in the wrong way, since it seems to think you have at least 6750 points. Without seeing more of the code, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong, though.

Comment: well do you thing that 50 are to much? Someone tells me that i have to take between 100 and 500 for 50 pictures with cats ... my set is much bigger but i've take 20 pictures to test this...edit:* code

Comment: You cannot cluster 20 points into 50 clusters with `KMeans`, it'll raise an exception. What's the shape of `data`?

Comment: the descriptors are compute by Sift: (X,128) with X between 0 and 3000...well but i have more then 20 points...i have 20 pictures with (x,128) sift descriptors :)

Comment: Then what are you trying to cluster?

Comment: I'm trying to built a classifier which recognize cats...so i'm trying to cluster the dataset (trainset Cats and non Cats pictures) for creating histogramms for the testset. And now i want to see how Kmeans cluster my training set

Comment: Fair enough. Again, what is `data.shape`?

Comment: data.shape  = (4883, 128) ... all Descriptors of the 20 pics "vstacked" together...maybe thats the fault ?!

Comment: The input to `KMeans.fit` is `(n_samples, n_features)` where `n_samples` should be 20. So yes, there's the error. If you stack the samples correctly, you'll get an error from `KMeans.fit` telling you that you can't learn 50 clusters from 20 samples.

Comment: ok so how is the right way to stack that all together ? I've got X_t_p that looks like `[[691,128],[783,128],...] and X_t_n that has the same shape...

Comment: I've no idea what that represents, but in any case, every sample should be a single row vector. Try `np.hstack`.

Comment: so n_samples should be the paths to the pictures or the binary data of the pictures ?

Comment: `n_samples` should be 20.

Comment: so the input should look like that ? [(1,[652,128]),(2,[726,128]),...] but how can i fix this ? at the moment i got a shape (20,) that looks like [[652,128],[767,128],...]

Answer (score 1):

If you cluster *SIFT descriptors*, your cluster means will look like sift descriptors, *not* like images.

I believe you were thinking of EigenFaces, but that has little to do with k-means.